# How to use id and data tags in a rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

Im trying to use data and id tags for a rails form like so whilst following [this guide](http://lab2023.com/using-medium-editor-as-input-field-in-rails.html) but it keeps coming up with an error:

```
<%= form_for(@article) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :title %>
<%=  f.hidden_field :body, html: { id: body } .editable { :data => { field: { id: body } } } %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong? I'm quite new to rails so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Sorry I should have put that in: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting '}' ...id: body } .editable { :data => { field: { id: body } } } );... ... ^

Comment: `<%= f.hidden_field :body, id: "body", class: "editable", :data => { :'field-id' => "body" } %>` *if* your data-attribute should look like `data-field-id="body"` **and** the `.editable` is your way of doing a `class` on the input field.

Comment: This does not look like valid ruby, the `.editable …` and the subsequent hash will not make any sense to the interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. I am making a few assumptions here.

1. First that your `.editable` is supposed to be a `class`.
2. That your data attribute should look like `data-field-id="body"`.

   `<%= f.hidden_field :body, :id => "body", :class => "editable", :data => { :"field-id" => "body" } %>`